# Programmatically building a Quicktabs instance

Tags: blocks

What I need to do is merge the usermenu ( user tasks ) with a Quicktabs menu I have on the same page.

So what I'm trying to do at the minute is to programmatically build a Quicktabs instance.

Based on the infomation at https://www.drupal.org/node/2119625  I have created a module 'userquicktabs'  heres the .module . Ive enabled the module, and I take it after this I should be able to see a new instance with the others instances I've created in the Quicktabs UI.  Do I need to make a block for the instance?

```
<?php


function userquicktabs() {
$tabs = array(
$tabs[] = array(
  'title'   => t('Node 1'),
  'type'    => 'node',
  'nid'     => '1',
  'weight'  => 0,
),
$tabs[] = array(
  'title'   => t('Node 2'),
  'type'    => 'node',
  'nid'     => '2',
  'weight'  => 1,
),
);

 // Configure the QuickTabs options
 $quicktabs_options = array(
'style'   => 'commons',
'ajax'    => FALSE,
'renderer'    => 'quicktabs',
);

$quicktabs_name = 'newinstance';

 print drupal_render(quicktabs_build_quicktabs($quicktabs_name, $quicktabs_options, $tabs));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, programmatically created instances are not registered with those created trough the UI, but at least they are more flexible.